# How to resolve org.json.JSONException: No value for index

Tags: json

I create a wallpaper apps and I found this error

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for index
```

and the apps can't start

Here's my json

```
]
{
    "wallpaper_index": "1",
    "wallpaper_name": "Wallpaper1",
    "wallpaper_site_name": "Wallpaper",
    "wallpaper_site_url": "http://google.com",
    "wallpaper_url": "https://i.imgur.com/Z0UGroX.jpg"
  },
  {
    "wallpaper_index": "2",
    "wallpaper_name": "Wallpaper2",
    "wallpaper_site_name": "Wallpaper",
    "wallpaper_site_url": "http://google.com",
    "wallpaper_url": "https://i.imgur.com/nSx1uN8.jpg"
  },
  {
    "wallpaper_index": "3",
    "wallpaper_name": "Wallpaper2",
    "wallpaper_site_name": "Wallpaper",
    "wallpaper_site_url": "http://google.com",
    "wallpaper_url": "https://i.imgur.com/ezhbnQR.jpg"
  },
]
```

How to fix it ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**: Your json is not valid. It should start with the "[" symbol ( and not with "]" one ) and you should remove the comma on
>   second-last row. Here is the correct json after the revision:
>
> ```
> [
>  {
>   "wallpaper_index":"1",
>   "wallpaper_name":"Wallpaper1",
>   "wallpaper_site_name":"Wallpaper",
>   "wallpaper_site_url":"http://google.com",
>   "wallpaper_url":"https://i.imgur.com/Z0UGroX.jpg"
>  },
>  {
>   "wallpaper_index":"2",
>   "wallpaper_name":"Wallpaper2",
>   "wallpaper_site_name":"Wallpaper",
>   "wallpaper_site_url":"http://google.com",
>   "wallpaper_url":"https://i.imgur.com/nSx1uN8.jpg"
>  },
>  {
>   "wallpaper_index":"3",
>   "wallpaper_name":"Wallpaper2",
>   "wallpaper_site_name":"Wallpaper",
>   "wallpaper_site_url":"http://google.com",
>   "wallpaper_url":"https://i.imgur.com/ezhbnQR.jpg"
>  }
> ]
> ```

By the way, assuming you just wrote the json wrong doing the question, the issue is that you are trying to get value for a not existing entry ( "index" ) on your json array elements.
According to your json, if you change for example the requested element to "wallpaper_index" it will work.